# Google App Script - TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined (line 13, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google App Script I'm trying to do a simple form first name and last name.

This is my **code.gs** code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("WebApp");
}

function userClicked(userInfo){
  var url ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157rmnmCU9d-vE2aDcbrf-VybEgjrIpZV4vkTmLitXvQ/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("WebApp");
  
ws.appendRow([userInfo.firstname,userInfo.lastname,new Date()]);
}
```

and this is my **WebApp.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Pago a Proveedores</h1>
   <label> First Name: </label><input type="string" id="first">
   <label> Last Name:</label><input type="string" id="Last">
   <button id= "butn">Add</button>
   <script>
    document.getElementById("butn").addEventListener("click", dosumthing);
    function dosumthing(){
    var userInfo={};
    userInfo.firstname=document.getElementById("first").value;
    userInfo.lastname=document.getElementById("Last").value;
    google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to execute the **function userClicked(userInfo)**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined (line 10,
> file "Code")

Can somebody help me out to solve this issue?

**Note:** This is the link of youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poVvrvs-m3Y that I'm following to do the form.

Comment: I thought that your script works. And from your script, I noticed that you are using Web Apps. So when you redeploy the Web Apps as new version and testing it again, what result will you obtain? I'm worry about that your Web Apps might not reflect the latest script. But this is my guess. So if my suggestion was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: Hi ! I have been able to successfully run your script with the expected behaviour and without encountering any issues. Could you please follow @Tanaike comment to redeploy the web app? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike thanks for your help. I did a redeploy the Web Apps as a new version and work perfectly thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf yes I did fallow Tanaike comment. Thanks for your time and help I really appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.